# How to click a hyperlink within a webpage using VBA?

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I am trying to click on a hyperlink within a webpage.

The HTML code:

```
<a name="#ICSrchTypeClassic" tabindex="18" class="PSHYPERLINK" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSrchTypeClassic');">Find an Existing Value</a>
```

I tried using the below code to run this by inner text:

```
Set AllHyperLinks = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
    If hyper_link.innerText = "Find an Existing Value" Then
        hyper_link.click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Nothing happens.

I tried other ways of clicking the hyperlink including execscript but get errors like

> "Object required"

or

> "action not supported by object"

Comment: ie,document.querySelector("[name='#ICSrchTypeClassic']").click or use ie.document.parentWindow.execScript to fire the function submitAction_win0 You may need to see if there are event listeners and if so use FireEvent "onclick" or attach an onclick HTMLEvent and dispatch it.

Comment: Is there a public url you can share?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share the url as it's our online based financial system. I am getting an error "the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"